# convert years and months into days in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

convert years and months into days.first convert back to years and months and now  want to convert back to days.code is like the one below

```
if len >366
len1 = cstr (math.floor(len/365))
len = len mod 365
len1 = len * 365
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What? What do you want to do?

Comment: want to covert something like this...365 days instead of 1 year.right now i manage to display 1 year but to convert back to days still got an error.hope its clear

Comment: Well, it isn't to be honest. What's the error?

Comment: i got an error for my years its not 365 but i turns to 24779.02 unless i put eg:len1 = cstr(len) i got 97 days still an error..so if this ones works i can convert my months into days and add(years+months+days) than divide the total(entered) to get the everage..:)

Comment: Post what you have for years months... how is this represented to you in your program? Can you convert it to an absolute date, or start and end dates? That would be best.

Comment: "I get an error" doesn't tell **what the error is**. What is the exact error message? Yes, it matters. Since you have yet to post it, did you even read it for content?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
days = years * 365.25
years = days / 365.25
```

Comment: @Saulis as for my code above i display something like that but still got the days error..but for years i got it correct

Comment: @markoz007 please do **NOT** accept this as an answer. Someone else may come along and think this is good coding, it isn't!

Comment: In my opinion, if you have information like "average life expectancy is 67 years" and you want to convert that into days, my method is enough. Of course, in some other situations it is not :)

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime.DaysInMonth Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx)

```
Dim July as integer = 7
' daysInJuly gets 31. 
Dim daysInJuly as integer = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2001, July);
```

Then to get the Days In Year:

```
Private Function GetDaysInAYear(year As Integer) As Integer
    Dim days As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    While i <= 13
        days += DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, i)
        i++
    End While
    Return days
End Function
```

Comment: There is an easier way to get days in a year: If DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) Then Return 366 Else Return 365 :)

Comment: Good point, not sure if that would work for 1753 tho.

Answer (score 0):

To get Days in a year you can simply do this:

```
Dim year As Integer = 2012  ' Set year here
Dim totalDaysInYear As Integer = New Date(year, 12, 31).Subtract(New Date(year, 1, 1)).Days
```

OR: (easy to understand)

```
Dim year As Integer = 2012    ' Set year here
Dim d1 As New Date(year, 1, 1)
Dim d2 As New Date(year, 12, 31)
Dim totalDaysInYear As Integer = d2.Subtract(d1).Days
```

To get days In month:

```
Dim year As Integer = 2012
Dim DaysInMonth As Integer = Date.DaysInMonth(year, 11)  ' Evaluates Nov 2012
```