# Convert average(decimal) into years, months and days

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I have been doing some calculation and able to find my solution but I want to go back to convert my `average(587.3)` into years, months and days. I'm using (ssrs 2008) for reporting. I have my `avg(Fields!XXX.Value)`to calculate the average inside my text box. Sorry for my English as this is my second language

Comment: This questions has already been discussed on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13132236/981380).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have "a number of days", then you don't need to take care of leap years etc, because this number (of days) doesn't refer to a "date". You might choose 360d/y and 30d/m as it is usually done in financial calculations.

Comment: can i do my calculation inside my expression field?to convert years months and days display if i have =avg(Fields!XXX.Value) within this code